# If it looks like a solid torus, walks like a solid torus, and quacks like a solid torus, is it a solid torus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

If an orientable 3-manifold $M$ has boundary the torus $S^1\times S^1$ and deform retracts to a solid torus $S^1\times D^2$, is it necessarily *homeomorphic* to a solid torus?

Equivalently, if the complement of a knot in a closed orientable 3-manifold deform retracts to a circle, is the knot complement a solid torus?

Comment: Therefore a solid torus is a duck. In particular it weighs the same as a duck, so it's made out of wood. And therefore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

First, since $\partial M \hookrightarrow M$ is not $\pi_1$-injective, by the Loop Theorem there is a properly embedded 2-disc $(D,\partial D) \hookrightarrow (M,\partial M)$ such that $\partial D$ does not bound a disc in the torus $\partial M$.

Second, letting $N$ be a regular neighborhood of $\partial M \cup D$, the surface $\partial N$ is a separating 2-sphere $S \subset \text{interior}(M)$. Let the closures of the components of $M-S$ be $M_1,M_2$ where $\partial M \subset M_1$.

Third, by hypothesis the inclusion $M_1 \hookrightarrow M$ is injective on $\pi_1$. Therefore by Van Kampen's theorem, $M_2$ is simply connected.

Fourth, by the Poincare Conjecture, now Perelman's Theorem, $M_2$ is a 3-ball (before Perelman one used to throw in the hypothesis "assume $M$ contains no fake 3-ball").

It follows that $M$ is a solid torus.

Comment: Perelman, not Pearlman. I think.

Comment: You wanted N to be a regular neighborhood of $\partial M \cup D$?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Since this answer helped me to move forward with my work when I was stuck, two comments for all others who would wander here in the years to follow. One, this argument is obviously algebraic and doesn't depend on there being a retract, just on having infinite cyclic fundamental group. Two, if $M$ is given even remotely concretely, this argument can be unwound to produce explicit homeomorphism, not relying on the black box of geometrization. But in full generality, a very nice solution!